# How to serialize and deserialize traits, to and from Json, in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, circe, spray-json

**First Attempt:**

So far I have tried spray-json. I have:

```
trait Base

case class A ( id: String) extends Base

case class B (id: String) extends Base
```

Now, for serializing and deserializing my `Base` type, I have the code:

```
implicit object BaseFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Base]{
    def write(obj: Base): JsValue = {
      obj match {
        case a: A => a.toJson
        case b: B => b.toJson
        case unknown @ _ => serializationError(s"Marshalling issue with ${unknown}")
      }
    }

    def read(json: JsValue): Base = {
      //how to know whether json is encoding an A or a B?
    }
  }
```

The problem is that, for implementing the `read` method for deserialization, I can't figure out a way to know whether the JsValue is encoding an `A` or a `B`.

**Second Attempt:**

For solving this in `spray-json`, I ended up simply renaming the field `id` in `A` to `aID`, and in `B` to `bID`.

**Third Attempt:**

Since `spray-json` was not as sophisticated as the alternative libraries such as `zio-json` or `circe`, which handle this issue by themselves without additional code, I started using `zio-json`

Now I get the error

`magnolia: could not infer DeriveJsonEncoder.Typeclass for type`

for all the case classes taking type parameters.
Also, it has problems with chained trait inheritance. It seems like circe uses magnolia, too. So it’s likely this would be replicated with circe, as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a discriminant value. If `A` and `B` there's no way to know to which type deserialize. One approach can be to add a `"_class"` attribute to the JSON which would contain `A` or `B`.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks. So in serializing it, I can add the` _class` attribute? how can I add an attribute to the `JsValue`? By the way, without it, if I use the `toString()` method of `JsValue`, wouldn’t it contain the class name?

Comment: @GaëlJ I ended up simply renaming the field `id` in `A` to `aID`, and in `B` to `bID`

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but this is the type of thing that your JSON library should do for you. There are plenty of possibilities, where the library will derive the serializer and deserializer for you at compile time, freeing you of these concerns while staying customizable. Checkout out circe or zio-json for two examples (there are other good ones too!)

Comment: @francoisr Thank you. Zio seemed better than circe, since I have lots of nested case classes and chains of inheritance from various traits. With spray-json, currently, just checking the Json Formats for each type takes lots of CPU overhead on the IDE, and it is very bug prone without the IDE check. Circe, as a much more mature library, does state that it has also overhead problems with nested case classes. I just cannot decide zio-json yet, because it is pre-release. So now I am rewriting things in akka-grpc instead of Akka-http which required serialization with json.

Comment: @francoisr But the authentication mechanism through GRPC is very much under-documented and there isn’t much material found on the internet on example implementation scenarios. What I am trying to do is authenticating with Akka-http and then passing the authentication result (the `User` instance) to the constructor of a new instance of the GRPC service with each request. This also allows for benefiting from HTTPS through Akka-http. I was just suspicious of this solution, since this definitely is not the standard way of doing it. Am I missing something on Json with Circe or Zio-json vs GRPC?

Comment: I would suggest you try circe or zio-json before you make assumption on their overhead cost. Trying them should be decently fast since it's a matter of adding two lines of encoder/decoder derivation to each sealed class hierarchy you need to encode/decode. The impact depends on your requirements, but premature optimization is the root of all evil, and development time should usually be more valued than CPU time.

Comment: @francoisr Thank you very much for the suggestions. I would be doing that.

Comment: @francoisr Just as one more question: is it better to define separate ‘flat’ case classes for both facilitating the serialization, and for decoupling the interface of the service from its logic, then write 'transformer’ methods for converting the logic objects to the transfer ones and vice versa; or is better to just directly serialize and deserialize the application logic objects?

Comment: I would stick with the most natural representation, probably nested case classes, and transfer that directly. You seem really worried about serialization performances, have you benchmarked that to be a problem for you? Remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil. If it turns out that nested json serialization is too slow for you (unlikely, but could be depending on what you're working on), you should look into protobuff rather than JSON. But I wouldn't do that unless you profile your code and see a problem with JSON serializers.

Comment: @francoisr I appreciate your input. The decoupling is mostly because I don’t want to change the client code every time the representation of objects in the application logic changes, for example by addition of new fields which facilitate processing. But with spray-json, simply writing the code for the conversion was too bug prone and time consuming.

Comment: @francoisr Now I am trying zio-json; I am concerned that I might not be using the library the right way. For example, there aren’t any examples on nested case classes out there. So I don’t know whether I should be adding encoders and decoders for each hierarchy level, or just adding them for the head case class that’s going to be transferred is enough.

Comment: I believe this choice is up to you. I personally add one encoder/decoder per case class, because it tends to fasten compilation, since the compiler does not have to derive the encoder/decoder for every case class everytime you make one small change. It also makes each case class more self-contained and decoupled from the rest of the data model. The trade-off is you have to write slightly more code (not much, 2 lines in the companion of each case class of your data model).

Comment: @francoisr Thanks for all this quality advice you shared with me in here. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @francoisr for the record, zio-json  produces the error ` magnolia: could not infer DeriveJsonEncoder.Typeclass for type` for all the case classes taking type parameters. Also, it has problems with chained trait inheritance. It seems like `circe` uses `magnolia`, too. So it’s likely this would be replicated with `circe` too. I am working with `MathML` and now I don’t know how to code the regular expressions in a flat way without generics or trait inheritance. I would appreciate any hint with this.

Comment: There is no way for the compiler to derive an encoder for a case class that uses a type parameter, because how would it know how to encode `case class Foo[T](t: T)` when it doesn't know anything about `T`? There are of course ways around this, but you should edit your question with more details about your actual use case so we can help.

Comment: @francoisr Thanks. I see. Even with type bounds for `T`, magnolia still has a problem. Since the client technologies for GRPC are not nearly as mature as the json-based ones, I think I would stick with `json` for client communication. But I am compromising type-safety for convenience, and I’m removing the generics from the application logic. Their other use was for avoiding code repetition for common computations. yet, it cannot get serialized. I also wonder about Jackson, which is used for `Akka` cluster communication.

Comment: Generic types should not be a problem for encoder/decoder derivation. I have added a proper answer that handles it with circe, but a similar solution should work for zio-json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should address this problem using a json encoding/decoding library.
Here is an example using circe and it's semi-automatic mode.

Since you mentionned in the comments that you are struggling with generic types in your case classes, I'm also including that. Basically, to derive an encoder or decoder for a class `Foo[T]` that contains a `T`, you have to prove that there is a way to encode and decode `T`. This is done by asking for an implicit `Encoder[T]` and `Decoder[T]` where you derive `Encoder[Foo[T]]` and `Decoder[Foo[T]]`. You can generalize this reasoning to work with more than one generic type of course, you just have to have an encoder/decoder pair implicitly available where you derive the encoder/decoder for the corresponding case class.

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._, io.circe.syntax._

case class Foo[T](a: Int, b: String, t: T)
object Foo {
  implicit def decoder[T: Encoder: Decoder]: Decoder[Foo[T]] = deriveDecoder
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder: Decoder]: Encoder[Foo[T]] = deriveEncoder
}

case class Bar(a: Int)
object Bar {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Bar] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Bar] = deriveDecoder
}

case class Baz(a: Int)

println(Foo(42, "hello", 23.4).asJson) // Works because circe knows Encoder[Float] 
println(Foo(42, "hello", Bar(42)).asJson) // Works because we defined Encoder[Bar] 

//println(Foo(42, "hello", Baz(42)).asJson) // Doesn't compile: circe doesn't know Encoder[Baz] in semi-auto mode
```

[Try it live on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zm2jvUJmRVOwYUZzSNmdeA)

Note that a different encoder/decoder for `Foo[T]` needs to be generated for each type `T` that you are using, which is why the encoder and decoder derivation for `Foo` have to be methods, not values like for `Bar`.

There is also a fully-automatic mode, but it tends to produce compile-time errors that are harder to debug for beginner, so I would start with semi-auto. Another problem, is that auto-mode can take much longer to compile on large projects. If you're feeling adventurous, it's even more beautiful when you don't make mistakes!

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._

case class Foo[T](a: Int, b: String, t: T)
case class Bar(a: Int)
case class Baz(a: Int)

println(Foo(42, "hello", 23.4).asJson) // circe knows Encoder[Float] and automatically derives Encoder[Foo[Float]]
println(Foo(42, "hello", Bar(42)).asJson) // circe wants Encoder[Foo[Bar]], so it ma(cro)gically derives Encoder[Bar] and then Encoder[Foo[Bar]]
println(Foo(42, "hello", Baz(42)).asJson) // Does compile this time, circe automatically find the encoder/decoder for Baz the same way it does for Bar
```

[Try it live on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7eeSdHeJRDO1tUuDNWYCDA)

Comment: Thank you. This took me a step closer. [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/G4uavCDZTj20y0d79Zakyw) is how my own code looks like. I think the reason it doesn’t compile is because the typing gets a little bit too convoluted here.

Comment: Now, this [one](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Sp2J2ccdSauvcPqA0UDdbQ) is working, with generic typing. Problem solved. Thanks:)

Comment: for further assisting anyone who would come across this question: [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9lw7Ep1NSnqzjT2v6NrCoA) is yet another more sophisticated working example with collections.

Comment: Would you please mind taking a look at why circe cannot derive the encoder for  `GeneralBaseContainer` in [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wFRpDqrWSsqsYQOCwV3nvA)?

Comment: When I define `GeneralBaseContainer` with generics everything works just fine. But when I write it with `MyBaseContainer[_]` instead of as `GeneralBaseContainer[T <: MyBase[T]](general: MyBaseContainer[T])` it doesn’t work.  In my use-case I cannot ‘propagate' the generics up-level because the upmost `model` case-class containing the rest of the hierarchy can contain many such `GeneralBaseContainer`s each with their own `T` as the specialization of `MyBase`.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but here is my solution. If it doesn't satisfy your domain constraint, please provide a more real-life example demonstrating what you're trying to achieve with all these containers. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uIlTiZ7KTiSEHYX2zYMl3A

Comment: I finally ended up with the conclusion that switching to GRPC has far less hassle than making json serialization work for a sophisticated message structure. Still, thank you very much for the solution. I greatly enjoyed reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

A working [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NpMc1PPhSUukT4xrxCeIUA) using traits with generics is this:

```
import io.circe.Decoder.Result
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.syntax._


trait MyBase[T <: MyBase[T]] {
  def myid: String
  def issue: MyBaseIssue
  def summary: MyBaseSummary[T]
}

trait MyBaseIssue

object MyBaseIssue {
  implicit val decodeIssue: Decoder[MyBaseIssue] =
    Decoder[SimpleBaseIssue].map[MyBaseIssue](identity).or(
      Decoder[SophisticatedBaseIssue].map[MyBaseIssue](identity)
    )

  implicit val encodeIssue: Encoder[MyBaseIssue] = Encoder.instance {
    case simple @ SimpleBaseIssue(_) => simple.asJson
    case sophisticated @ SophisticatedBaseIssue(_) => sophisticated.asJson

  }
}

trait MyBaseSummary[T <: MyBase[T]]

object MyBaseSummary {
  implicit def decodeSummary[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[MyBaseSummary[T]] =
    Decoder[SimpleBaseSummary].map[MyBaseSummary[SimpleBase]](identity).asInstanceOf[Decoder[MyBaseSummary[T]]].or(
      Decoder[SophisticatedBaseSummary].map[MyBaseSummary[SophisticatedBase]](identity).asInstanceOf[Decoder[MyBaseSummary[T]]]
    )


  implicit def encodeSummary[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[MyBaseSummary[T]] = Encoder.instance {
    case simple @ SimpleBaseSummary(_) => simple.asJson
    case sophisticated @ SophisticatedBaseSummary(_) => sophisticated.asJson

  }
}

case class SimpleBase(
                       myid: String,
                       override val issue: SimpleBaseIssue,
                       override val summary: SimpleBaseSummary
                     ) extends MyBase[SimpleBase]

case class SophisticatedBase(
                              myid: String,
                              extraField: String,
                              override val issue: SophisticatedBaseIssue,
                              override val summary: SophisticatedBaseSummary
                            ) extends MyBase[SophisticatedBase]

object SimpleBase {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SimpleBase] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SimpleBase] = deriveDecoder
}

object SophisticatedBase {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SophisticatedBase] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SophisticatedBase] = deriveDecoder
}

case class SimpleBaseIssue(simpleIssueType: String) extends MyBaseIssue
case class SophisticatedBaseIssue(sophisticatedIssueType: String) extends MyBaseIssue

object SimpleBaseIssue {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SimpleBaseIssue] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SimpleBaseIssue] = deriveDecoder
}

object SophisticatedBaseIssue {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SophisticatedBaseIssue] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SophisticatedBaseIssue] = deriveDecoder
}

case class SimpleBaseSummary(simpleSummary: String) extends MyBaseSummary[SimpleBase]

case class SophisticatedBaseSummary(sophisticatedSummary: String) extends MyBaseSummary[SophisticatedBase]

object SimpleBaseSummary {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SimpleBaseSummary] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SimpleBaseSummary] = deriveDecoder
}

object SophisticatedBaseSummary {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SophisticatedBaseSummary] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SophisticatedBaseSummary] = deriveDecoder
}

case class MyBaseList[T <: MyBase[T]](
                                       myid: String,
                                       var membersMap: Map[String, T] = Map.empty,
                                       override val issue: MyBaseListIssues[T],
                                       override val summary: MyBaseListSummary[T]
                                     ) extends MyBase[MyBaseList[T]]

object MyBaseList {

  implicit def membersMapDecoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[Map[String, T]] = Decoder.decodeMap
  implicit def membersMapEncoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[Map[String, T]] = Encoder.encodeMap


  implicit def encoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[MyBaseList[T]] = deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[MyBaseList[T]] = deriveDecoder
}

case class MyBaseListIssues[T <: MyBase[T]](
                                             issue: String,
                                             var set: Set[MyBaseIssue] = Set[MyBaseIssue]()
                                           ) extends MyBaseIssue

object MyBaseListIssues {
  implicit def membersMapDecoder: Decoder[Set[MyBaseIssue]] =
    Decoder.decodeSet[MyBaseIssue]
  implicit def membersMapEncoder: Encoder[Set[MyBaseIssue]] = Encoder.encodeSet

  implicit def encoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[MyBaseListIssues[T]] = deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[MyBaseListIssues[T]] = deriveDecoder
}

case class MyBaseListSummary[T <: MyBase[T]](
                                              summaryList: Map[String, MyBaseSummary[T]]
                                            ) extends MyBaseSummary[MyBaseList[T]]

object MyBaseListSummary {

  implicit def membersMapDecoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[Map[String, MyBaseSummary[T]]] = Decoder.decodeMap
  implicit def membersMapEncoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[Map[String, MyBaseSummary[T]]] = Encoder.encodeMap


  implicit def encoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Encoder[MyBaseListSummary[T]] = deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[T <: MyBase[T]: Encoder: Decoder]
  : Decoder[MyBaseListSummary[T]] = deriveDecoder
}



object MainObject extends App {
  val simpleList = MyBaseList[SimpleBase]("simpleId",
    Map("one" -> SimpleBase("baseid", SimpleBaseIssue("the mistake"), SimpleBaseSummary("very concise"))),
    MyBaseListIssues[SimpleBase]("listIssue", Set(SimpleBaseIssue("a disaster"))),
    MyBaseListSummary[SimpleBase]( Map("simplebaseid" -> SimpleBaseSummary("super concise")))
  )
  val simpleJson = simpleList.asJson
  println(simpleJson)
  val convertedSimpleList = simpleJson.as[MyBaseList[SimpleBase]]
  println(convertedSimpleList)


  val sphisticatedList = MyBaseList[SophisticatedBase]("sophisticatedId",
    Map("one" -> SophisticatedBase("baseid", "further detail", SophisticatedBaseIssue("the mistake"), SophisticatedBaseSummary("very concise"))),
    MyBaseListIssues[SophisticatedBase]("listIssue", Set(SophisticatedBaseIssue("a disaster"))),
    MyBaseListSummary[SophisticatedBase]( Map("sophisticatedbaseid" -> SophisticatedBaseSummary("super concise")))
  )
  val sophisticatedJson = sphisticatedList.asJson

  println(sophisticatedJson)

  val convertedSophisticatedListDecoder: Result[MyBaseList[SophisticatedBase]] = sophisticatedJson.as[MyBaseList[SophisticatedBase]]

  println(convertedSophisticatedListDecoder)

  convertedSophisticatedListDecoder match {
    case Left(failure) => println(failure)
    case Right(list) => println(list)
  }
}
```

It is still essential to make sure every case class inheriting a particular trait has a different number of fields from the others inheriting the same trait, or it at least differs with the other case classes in the naming of those fields.

Otherwise, the decoder would not do its job correctly and decode the json as the first case class matching it in the decoder function, instead of the correct intended one.