# Extracting the n´th element of a json response in Scala/Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

I have a response body in json where I want to extract the value: ID_ADFA0741-6A46-4A90-8AAE-BC7DB18B27E1

In the below json structure.

```
.check(jsonPath("$..key").saveAs("key")))
```

gives me the value M01A

How could I use a check to obtain the value "key" for the element number 2 (the second occuerence of "key" below?

```
{"libItems":[{"hasNotes":false,"drugs":[{"ingredientNamesAndStrengths":[{"ingredientNames":["Diklofenak"],"strengths":["50 mg"]}],"order":0,"form":"Enterotab"}],"treatmentType":"Brand","isSupplement":false,"nameOfBrand":"Voltaren","nameFormStrength":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","medicationUsedFor":{"value":"TEST"},"clinicalWarnings":[],"dataWarnings":[{"practitionerName":"ELENA FOS ENGELUND","importDate":"2021-08-16T18:13:06.597+02:00","isNewTreatment":true,"type":"Import","isMarkedAsHandled":false}],"warningReferences":[{"key":"M01A","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"},{"key":"ID_ADFA0741-6A46-4A90-8AAE-BC7DB18B27E1","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"},{"key":"ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"}],"usage":"Fixed","atc":"M01AB05","atcNames":"Diklofenak","shortDose":{"key":"160","value":"1x3"},"drugId":"ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD","hasIngredientNames":true,"prescriptionActions":["Stop","ConfirmUse","Renew","Prescribe"],"id":"440a01f5-1df8-4f26-a6c1-08d95cab00c7","treatmentId":"00be4297-cc9f-432d-30d6-08d95cab00c7","treatmentStart":"2021-06-02T00:00:00","dssnText":"1 tablett 3 ganger daglig","actionStatus":"ActionRequired","treatmentStatus":"Active","externalUpdate":"New","approvalStatus":"Empty","resepts":[{"localReseptState":"None","rfReseptState":"AvailableForDispatch"}],"diffPreviousValues":[],"hasRfError":false,"isLocked":false,"guardianAccessReservation":false,"paperReseptDispensation":false,"reseptPidState":"NoChange"}],"fibItems":[],"nibItems":[],"vaccines":[],"vibInformation":{"vibStatus":"ActionRequired","messagesToSign":{"new":0,"renewed":0,"changed":0,"stopped":0,"removed":0,"recalled":0,"registration":0,"stoppedLocalRegistration":0},"actionRequired":{"treatments":1,"nutritions":0,"consumables":0,"vaccines":0,"allergies":0,"warnings":0},"previousLibItems":["ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD"]}}
```

Comment: Why don’t you parse the Json in a case class using some Json serialization library such as circe, spray-json, or zip-json, and then work with the obtained case class?

Comment: Hi, not very familiar with these libraries. Could you show me an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you using `akka` or `The Play Framework`?

Comment: One example is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119808/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-traits-to-and-from-json-in-scala) I have both asked and written a working answer for, with a runnable `scastie` piece.

Comment: I wrote a working example in the answer for your case.

Comment: Hey, thank you for accepting my answer. I would appreciate an upvote, if it truly helped you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since, in the comments, the OP requested an example of using a Json parsing/serialization library for constructing case classes from the provided Json, for the accessing and processing of the desired fields; here is a simplified working [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QfmYBw0wTHKV3KZ34euEKQ)  with `circe`:

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._,  io.circe.parser._

val myShortJsonString = 

"""{"libItems":
      [
          {
            "hasNotes":false,
            "warningReferences":[
                {"key":"M01A", "drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg", "refType":"Atc" },
                
                { "key":"ID_ADFA0741-6A46-4A90-8AAE-BC7DB18B27E1", "drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg", "refType":"Atc" },
                
                { "key": "ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD", "drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg", "refType":"Atc" }
              ]
            
          }
      ]
   
    }"""

val myFullJsonString = 

"""{"libItems":
      [
          {
            "hasNotes":false,
            "drugs":[
                 {"ingredientNamesAndStrengths":[{"ingredientNames":["Diklofenak"],"strengths":["50 mg"]}],
                  "order":0,
                  "form":"Enterotab"}
                  ],
            "treatmentType":"Brand",
            "isSupplement":false,
            "nameOfBrand":"Voltaren",
            "nameFormStrength":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg",
            "medicationUsedFor":{"value":"TEST"},
            "clinicalWarnings":[],
            "dataWarnings":[{"practitionerName":"ELENA FOS ENGELUND","importDate":"2021-08-16T18:13:06.597+02:00","isNewTreatment":true,"type":"Import","isMarkedAsHandled":false}],
            "warningReferences":[
              {"key":"M01A","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"},
              {"key":"ID_ADFA0741-6A46-4A90-8AAE-BC7DB18B27E1","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"},
              {"key":"ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD","drugName":"Diklofenak Enterotab 50 mg","refType":"Atc"}],
            "usage":"Fixed",
            "atc":"M01AB05",
            "atcNames":"Diklofenak",
            "shortDose":{"key":"160","value":"1x3"},
            "drugId":"ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD",
            "hasIngredientNames":true,
            "prescriptionActions":["Stop","ConfirmUse","Renew","Prescribe"],
            "id":"440a01f5-1df8-4f26-a6c1-08d95cab00c7",
            "treatmentId":"00be4297-cc9f-432d-30d6-08d95cab00c7",
            "treatmentStart":"2021-06-02T00:00:00",
            "dssnText":"1 tablett 3 ganger daglig",
            "actionStatus":"ActionRequired",
            "treatmentStatus":"Active",
            "externalUpdate":"New",
            "approvalStatus":"Empty",
            "resepts":[{"localReseptState":"None","rfReseptState":"AvailableForDispatch"}],
            "diffPreviousValues":[],
            "hasRfError":false,
            "isLocked":false,
            "guardianAccessReservation":false,
            "paperReseptDispensation":false,
            "reseptPidState":"NoChange"
          }
      ],
    "fibItems":[],
    "nibItems":[],
    "vaccines":[],
    "vibInformation":{
                            "vibStatus":"ActionRequired",
                            "messagesToSign":{
                                           "new":0,
                                           "renewed":0,
                                           "changed":0,
                                           "stopped":0,
                                           "removed":0,
                                           "recalled":0,
                                           "registration":0,
                                           "stoppedLocalRegistration":0
                                           },
                            "actionRequired":{
                                           "treatments":1,
                                            "nutritions":0,
                                            "consumables":0,
                                            "vaccines":0,
                                            "allergies":0,
                                            "warnings":0
                                            },
                            "previousLibItems":["ID_BD1BDC3F-1FCF-4944-99BC-6B3E8EAAD6FD"]
                      }
    }"""

case class Library(libItems: List[LibItem],
                   // fibItems: List[FibItem], nibItems: List[NibItem], vaccines: List[Vaccine], vibInformation: VibInformation
                  )

case class LibItem(hasNotes: Boolean, 
                   //drugs: List[Drug],
                   warningReferences: List[WarningReference])

case class WarningReference(key: String, drugName: String, refType: String)

val maybeLibraryJsonObject = parse(myShortJsonString)
val maybeLibrary = maybeLibraryJsonObject match {
  case Right(libraryJsonObject) =>  libraryJsonObject.as[Library] 
  case Left(failure) => println(failure)
}

maybeLibrary match {
  case Right(libraryResult) => 
     println(libraryResult)
     val libItems = libraryResult.asInstanceOf[Library].libItems
     val libItem = libItems(0)
     val warningReferenceKey = libItem.warningReferences(1).key 

     val warningReferenceKeySections = warningReferenceKey.split("-")

      val  code = warningReferenceKeySections(3)+"-"+warningReferenceKeySections(4)

   println("code: " + code) 

  case Left(failure) => println(failure)
}
```

To make it work for the full json string, you need to create case classes for all of its fields, as in the commented section.

Comment: Gatling already has all needed logic for extract from json.
You can view my answer below with simple solution

Comment: @Amerousful This is an alternative solution, which makes the processing of also other fields much more easier and accessible. This answer is also written at the request of the person asking the question, in the comments, who asked for an example of what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there is a two ways.

The first - you can 'directly' define which element you need to extract:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.[1].key").saveAs("key")))
```

The second way - you can save all elements and then use the desired via Gatling EL:

```
.check(jsonPath("$..key").findAll.saveAs("keys")))

"${keys(1)}"
```