# Strange jsonpath not able to capture (Gatling/Scala)

Tags: scala, jsonpath, gatling

I have a responsebody that looks like this:

```
[   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "735938006",     "display": "akutt hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "267096005",     "display": "frontal hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "103011009",     "display": "godartet anstrengelseshodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "25064002",     "display": "hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "38823002",     "display": "hodepine med aura"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "193031009",     "display": "klasehodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "230465000",     "display": "migrene med aura uten hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "330007",     "display": "oksipital hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "54012000",     "display": "posttraumatisk hodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "4969004",     "display": "sinushodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "398057008",     "display": "tensjonshodepine"   },   {     "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",     "code": "128187005",     "display": "vaskulær hodepine"   } ]
```

and I want to capture the value "hodepine" element 3 from the top. I use IntelliJ and "Copy JSON Pointer" and it gives me this:

```
/3/display
```

This does not work using it in Gatling/Scala like this:

```
.check(jsonPath("$../3/display").saveAs("display"))
```

The error is:

```
> jsonPath($../3/display).find.exists, found nothing
```

Any tips on how to obtain the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68907167/7512201) on similar question and it can be helpful for you.

For your case: `$.[3].display`